# 403 Forbidden error only for wikipedia site

Tags: networking, firefox, browser, isp

So I was browsing the Internet and everything was nice and dandy suddenly my favorite site [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org) gave me this:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this page.
```

I have been trying desperately to get it work for a while now, but I just cannot! Things I have tried:

- Firstly I deleted all my cache, cookies, offline data etc from
  Firefox (which is the browser I always use) but it didn't help.
- Then I tried with a bunch of browsers including Chrome, IE and Safari
  but it didn't work.
- Then I downloaded Opera and tried but it didnt work.
- Then I used `ipconfig/release` and `ipconfig/renew` to reset my IP
  but it didnt work.
- Then I called my ISP and asked them to reset my modem from their end,
  which they did. Then I restarted everything from my modem, router,
  laptop, browser but it didnt work.

I don't know what else to do!

A few more observations:

- This only happens when I am connecting to Internet using this
  particular ISP.
- If I use another service provider, I can access wikipedia without
  problems
- If I use Tor to access wikipedia when connected using the problematic
  ISP, I can access without problems
- The site I have trouble with is en.wikipedia.org - www.wikipedia.org
  and all other language sites work.

A totally silly, unrelated and kind of creepy trivia:

This started at the exact instant when I went to wikipedia to read about this ghost story that I had been following for the past two days, I was able to access wikipedia just fine a few mins prior to that...Lol I know its silly :p

Anyways, I am at a loss as to what is causing this - do you think I should try exorcism as a last resort :-( I am at a loss to what else to try now, is there any firewall rules I can check? I am using firefox on windows 8.1

Comment: Have you asked the ISP to fix it, since this appears to be something they are doing?

Comment: Try a different DNS server than what the ISP gives you.

Comment: @fixer1234 They said that they are not getting that issue when they try from their end. The reset my modem, I do not know what else to ask them...

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - how do i do that?

Comment: Modify your network settings and put in a differnet DNS server. Say, Google's (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4) - here's their documentation on it: https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using

Comment: Can you post the output of 'nslookup en.wikipedia.org' to make sure that DNS is pointing you to the right address?